# Why are the queries in SQL mostly written in Capital Letters?

Tags: sql

I have often seen the queries written in SQL in *CAPITAL LETTERS*. Though I think SQL is not case sensitive, why do most of them prefer to write in *CAPITAL LETTERS* ? Is it just a matter of choice or does it have some logic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are MySQL queries almost always written in Capital](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325927/why-are-mysql-queries-almost-always-written-in-capital)

Comment: IF YOU WRITE YOUR QUERIES LIKE THIS THE SERVER WILL HEAR THEM BETTER AND EXECUTE THEM BEFORE quieter queries, written like this. At least that's what I think, and why my queries are mostly written in capital letters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lowercase or uppercase for SQL Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566164/lowercase-or-uppercase-for-sql-statements)

Comment: Given they are not needed and reading them is known to be harder to read - https://www.mity.com.au/blog/writing-readable-content-and-why-all-caps-is-so-hard-to-read - I would encourage ditching the ALLCAPS convention entirely.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It was meant for readability.  Before, SQL was written in plain-text editors (no syntax/code highlighting) and keywords needed to be differentiated for better readability and maintenance.

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name = column_value
```

vs

```
select column_name from table_name where column_name = column_value
```

See the difference?  The first word in each line told the reader exactly what was going on (selecting something from somewhere where something).

But now with syntax-highlighting, there's really no point.  But it IS a best practice and allows SQL developers to be on the same page/style while developing.

Answer (score 4):

It varies with when you learned SQL and who or where you learned it from.

It originated on IBM mainframes and those definitely preferred upper-case.

These days, I write the keywords in all-caps and the database objects in either lower-case or in SuitablyMixedCase.  That simply makes it easy to see the keywords, while leaving the important information (table names, column names, etc) in more readable mainly lower-case letters.  It makes it trivial to read past the keywords.

Of course, I've been writing SQL for...ulp...over twenty-five years, so lots of stuff like this is simply 'second nature' and 'the way I've always done it'.  But I find it makes for more readable SQL.

Answer (score 2):

SQL is a case insensitive programming language, whether u write in CAPITAL or not it will not affect your logic. It is basically done to increase the readability of SQL Query

Comment: Thats what the Exact Duplicate Question's Answer says, so what different is your answer...!

Comment: may be they both posted within a few seconds time difference.

Answer (score 2):

Entry level SQL:1992 is case sensitive and requires that identifiers (SQL keywords) are in upper case only. Or should I say "required": case insensitive identifiers has been a core standard feature since SQL:1999. I would guess that upper case keywords was the vernacular for programming language design in the late sixties/early seventies.

Nowadays putting SQL keywords in upper case is merely a matter of taste and is my personal preference. I agree that it aids readability and this is why I use lower case for attribute names (with underscore element separators e.g. `birth_date`) and upper camel case for table names. Not coincidentally, these are the recommended conventions in the only book on SQL heuristics, [Joe Celko's SQL Programming Style](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Joe_Celko_s_SQL_programming_style.html?id=90c41yKz3IUC&redir_esc=y).

Answer (score 1):

It's for readability.  If we didn't have colored keywords, CAPS would allow us to distinguish keywords.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real purpose to it, it is simply a choice of style or convention. It wouldn't affect your them either way, personally I keep all of mine lower case.

Answer (score -5):

SQL compiler translates the query written by use to upper case before compiling, It's good to write it in upper case for fast processing

Comment: _write it in upper case for fast processing_ can you please justify this?