# SQL Query Optimization -Slowing the Server

Tags: sql, performance, optimization

The system I maintain seems to slow down quite a bit every few days, and I assume it's from a bad query somewhere.

From what I can tell, I've narrowed the issue down to a page or two. Here's the query on the page that I think is causing the issue.

```
select a.s_purchase_order as order_id, a.order_type, a.nobackorder, a.order_note, a.note, a.rqst_dlvry_date, b.customer_name ,c.store_name,(c.store_name + ',' + isnull(c.address1 + ',', ' ') +  isnull(c.city + ',', ' ') +  isnull(c.state_cd+ ',', ' ')  + isnull( c.zipcode, ' ')) as store_info, d.supplier_account
from VW_CustomerOrder a, Customer b, Store c, eligible_supplier d
where a.customer = c.customer
and a.store = c.store
and a.customer = b.customer
and c.customer *= d.customer
and c.store *= d.store
and a.supplier *= d.supplier
and a.purchase_order = @order_id
and a.customer = @customer_id
and a.store=@store_id
and a.supplier = @supplier_id
```

Is there something obvious there that would be very slow or cause the system to slow over time?

Comment: Do your joins in the From clause (like the answer below) not in the where clause, it improves readability. Also, what DBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? other?

Comment: @Yaroslav Don't impose your own syntax preferences on others. Your uppercase SQL keywords are no more correct than lowercase keywords, and they look (in my opinion) hideous.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is a good idea, but I'm getting an error now. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Sir yes sir! ...the hideuos, in my opinion, was unnecessary http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/  For me is easier to differentiate keywords from columns, tables, etc, I'm aware of the colours, but in my opinion is more readable...but yes, I should not impose my preference... nevertheless: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608196/why-should-i-capitalize-my-sql-keywords   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292026/is-there-a-good-reason-to-use-upper-case-for-t-sql-keywords  And last but not least, I think that at least the identation should be kept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about do some inner joins to solve this, check your base and see index and foreign keys for those table, this always is helpful in querys and performance

```
select 
  a.columun_a, b.column_a from table_a a 
inner join table_b b on a.id = b.id
where 
  b.column_b = "some value"
```

Comment: This seems like a great idea, but when I add them I get this error: `1016, Level 15, State 3, Procedure sp_s_getCustOrderSummary, Line 12
Outer join operators cannot be specified in a query containing joined tables.`

Comment: I changed it to `from VW_CustomerOrder a inner join Customer b on a.customer = b.customer inner join Store c on a.customer = c.customer inner join eligible_supplier d on a.customer = d.customer`